# Create a 0 - 1 float based on how far user has panned?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

If the title's not clear, I apologize. Late nights have a bad effect.

I'm trying to make certain elements fade away with my pan gesture. Here's my current code to get a float value to be used as an alpha level.

```
float cueAlpha = [recognizer translationInView:self.backgroundView].y / 600;
```

Please note: the backgroundView is not the main view controller. It's a view controller.

I've also NSLogged the value to see what it was putting out, and never would it go past .75. I need the alpha to be 0 - 1. If you could also show me how to make it so it's 1 - 0, that would be fabulous.

EDIT: I should mention that I want it to be values BETWEEN 0 and 1, not either or. Thank you, @rmaddy for pointing that out.

EDIT 2: I answered my own question here, but here it is to anyone who's interested in seeing what I did. Credit to @Reconquistador for telling me about the frame.height idea.

```
float cueAlpha = [recognizer locationInView:self.view].y / self.view.frame.size.height;
```

Comment: Unclear. Do want a value between 0.0 and 1.0 or do want one of two values - either 0 or 1?

Comment: @rmaddy between 0 and 1. I'm sorry, I should have specified. I'll change the OP to reflect that.

Comment: You need to divide the value by the largest possible value. If the value can be between 0 and *x* then divide by *x* (be sure to do float division and not integer division).

Comment: @rmaddy I've done that before, that's the worst thing. It always ends up not going to 1, it goes to about .75 when the gesture stops. And .58 when it starts. How would you go about it?

Comment: You don't provide enough information to know. What is the min and max value your get before doing the division?

Comment: @rmaddy what do you mean by that? It's doing the division dynamically based on where the view is being dragged in the y direction and 600, which is the coordinate of y where it really doesn't matter if it's 1 alpha or not, the animation will take care of the rest. But I'm trying to smoothly blend the alpha on the way down with the pan gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 600 is bigger than maximal height, you will never get up to 1. Use self.backgroundView.frame.size.height instead of 600. That is even better to make, as if you will change size of backgroundView, you will not need to alter your code.

Comment: I've updated my edit to show that I got the answer down. Thanks for your help!